# Difference between add_filter and apply_filters

Tags: plugins, customization

I have searched for a suitable explanation of the difference between `add_filter()` and `apply_filters()` in here but couldn't find one.

Can anyone tell me what information or logic to consider before using `add_filter` or `apply_filters` in one context.

That makes the use of one imperative and not the other ?

- Is it correct that `add_filter` just adds a function to the queue of functions waiting to be executed on a variable and `apply_filters` executes the functions in order?
- Is it also correct that `apply_filters` when called with an argument (the name of the function to be run) will execute that function before all the others (if they exist) in the queue?

Comment: What about the existing documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) does not explain it adequately for you?

Comment: I think this is actually a good question. As a new wordpress dev this can be a confusing concept.

Answer (score 33):

Most of the following can be found in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/):

---

[`apply_filters`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters)

> The callback functions attached to filter hook `$tag` are invoked by calling this function. This function can be used to create a new filter hook by simply calling this function with the name of the new hook specified using the $tag parameter.

```
$value = apply_filters( $tag, $value, $var_1, $var_2, ... );
```

**In essence:**
You use `apply_filters` to *filter* a given `$value` - with respect to the value itself as well as optionally provided variables `$var_1` through `$var_n`.

---

[`add_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)

> Hook a function to a specific filter action.

```
add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

**In essence:**
You use `add_filter` to hook a custom function to the given filter action (`$tag`), which you might have generated by `apply_filters` before (or it was a built-in filter action or stems from a plugin/your theme).

---

So, here's a *fictional* example:

```
function print_initials( $name ) {

    if ( ! is_string( $name ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $fragments = explode( ' ', $name );

    /**
     * Filter wether to print initials in reverse order.
     *
     * @param bool $reverse Print initials in reverse order?
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'reverse_initials', FALSE ) ) {
        $fragments = array_reverse( $fragments );
    }

    foreach ( $fragments as $f ) {
        echo substr( $f, 0, 1 );
    }
}

print_initials( 'Some Guy' ); // outputs: SG

add_filter( 'reverse_initials', '__return_true' );

print_initials( 'Some Guy' ); // outputs: GS
```

Now, if we just call our function as is, the initials are printed from left to right—because this is what we defined as default behavior.

The second time, we get the initials in reverse order—because the filter function `__return_true`, which is hooked to our filter action, always returns `TRUE` and thus makes the initials be output from right to left.

Comment: This is a great answer and shows how you can override filters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example above is the classic example that kills a newby developer..
explained in a rude - people-friendly way, you can use apply_filters to create a specific custom filter you can later on modify through add_filter.
On the other side, if you use an already made hook, you can straight use add_filter..
The logic, is the tipical non-logic of development, so you need to look more examples and practice a bit in order to "understand" how they work..
I know that even my explanation could not sound totally clear, (and most of our coworkers could kill me for being incorrect) but it looks to me the most understandable explanation I have found on the Internet..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261954)